# Checking how Google robot sees local website

Tags: seo, robots.txt

How to check how Google robot sees my local website?

Is there an official Google tool? I've heard of one that check online websites, but what about locally site not avaible on network?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Google Webmasters Tools allow crawling or fetching local site. 
Also, in addition to crawling local site, you'll have to make sure your local site or URLs don't get crawled in Google search as it will devalue your live site in future.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use fetch as googlebot in webmaster tools to see how google views your site.

Comment: But my website is local, it's inaccessable from Internet.